# my sound play and stop successefully for first time but when i set another alarm sound the it play but not stopped on the close button

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

When I set an alarm it fired successfully and sound play and stop successfully on close button but when a second alarm is set it fired successfully but on closed alarm button the sound is not stop.

in .h file I have this one

```
{
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer_;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer_;
```

in .m file I have this one

```
// alarm close button to close the alarm
- (IBAction)btnCloseAlaram:(id)sender {

    [self.audioPlayer_ stop];

    [self.audioPlayer_ release];

    [self hideViews];
}

// sound setting method this method is for when I selected the sound from a table view it call this method for selection of specific sound name to play when alarm is fired
-(void)alarmSounds
{
    //checks for different sounds to be selected 
    GET_DEFAULTS
    NSURL *url =nil;

    if ([defaults integerForKey:@"Checked"]==0) {

        url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/1.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    }
   //checks for different sounds to be selected 
    else if ([defaults integerForKey:@"Checked"]==1) {

        url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/2.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    }
    else if ([defaults integerForKey:@"Checked"]==2) {

        url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/3.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    }
    else if ([defaults integerForKey:@"Checked"]==3) {

        url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/4.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    }
    else if ([defaults integerForKey:@"Checked"]==4) {

        url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/5.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    }
    else if ([defaults integerForKey:@"Checked"]==5) {

        url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/6.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    }
    else if ([defaults integerForKey:@"Checked"]==6) {

        url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/7.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    }
    else if ([defaults integerForKey:@"Checked"]==7) {

        url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/8.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    }
    else if ([defaults integerForKey:@"Checked"]==8) {

        url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/9.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    }
    else if ([defaults integerForKey:@"Checked"]==9) {

        url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/10.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    }
    else if ([defaults integerForKey:@"Checked"]==10) {

        url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/11.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    }

    NSError *error;

    self.audioPlayer_ = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

    self.audioPlayer_.numberOfLoops = 1;

    [self.audioPlayer_ play];
}
```

Comment: You need to call [self.audioPlayer_ stop] & [self.audioPlayer_ release] in your alarmSounds method - basically you need to do this in order to stop any playing sounds... it may be a good idea to test if it is nil first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a stopAudio method...

```
- (void) stopAudio {
  if(self.audioPlayer_ != nil) {
    [self.audioPlayer_ stop];
    [self.audioPlayer_ release];
    self.audioPlayer_ = nil;
  }
}
```

then you can call this method both in your btnCloseAlaram() and alarmSounds() methods...